# Can you use CHARINDEX and LEN together to return the specific number of characters between two delimiters?

Tags: sql, substring, charindex

I have a specific piece of code, as follows:

```
DECLARE @hello VARCHAR(100) = 'B:Technical Issue; L:XML; R:my-repo'
```

Using three separate SUBSTRING() queries, I want to return three separate strings. For example, using a query on 'B:', I want to return 'Technical Issue'. For 'L:', I want to return 'XML', etc. As you can see, for 'R:' there is no ';' to reference the end of the string. Basically, I want to return the values between the first ':' and then a ';', if there is one, or the end of the string if not.

All I've got so far (which doesn't work) is the below (for 'B:'):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@hello, 
CHARINDEX('B:', @hello) +2, 
CHARINDEX(':', @hello, CHARINDEX(';', @hello)+ 1)  - CHARINDEX(':', @hello) - 1) WHERE @hello LIKE '%B:%'
```

So, is there a way to utilise LEN and CHARINDEX to find the length of the string I need, either using ';' or the end of the string as the second delimiter?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this as below:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@hello, 
CHARINDEX('B:', @hello)+2,CASE WHEN RIGHT(@hello, LEN(@hello)-CHARINDEX('B:', @hello)) LIKE '%;%' 
THEN CHARINDEX(';', @hello, CHARINDEX('B:', @hello, 0)) - CHARINDEX('B:', @hello, 0) - 2 
ELSE LEN(@hello) END)
```